# im trying to format my json file using d3.json(). Can anyone help me

Tags: d3.js, drupal-6

using d3.json how to convert from this format

[{"HANDLERID":"AET55V8366","HANDLER_MODEL":"AETRIUM 55V8",
"START1":"2014-03-30 00:00:00","END1":"2014-06-17 02:44:11","VAL1":"49.7950",
"START2":"2014-06-17 02:44:11","END2":"2014-07-18 18:13:51","VAL2":"69.7130",
"START3":"2014-07-18 18:13:51","END3":"2014-09-04 05:28:22","VAL3":"99.00"},

{"HANDLERID":"AET55V8441","HANDLER_MODEL":"AETRIUM 55V8",
"START1":"2014-02-19 00:00:00","END1":"2014-05-28 05:23:15","VAL1":"50.0350",
"START2":"2014-05-28 05:23:15","END2":"2014-07-06 12:20:33","VAL2":"70.0490",
"START3":"2014-07-06 12:20:33","END3":"2014-09-03 10:46:30","VAL3":"100.00"},

{"HANDLERID":"AET55V8445","HANDLER_MODEL":"AETRIUM 55V8",
"START1":"2014-06-14 00:00:00","END1":"2014-07-23 09:36:38","VAL1":"51.7700",
"START2":"2014-07-23 09:36:38","END2":"2014-08-08 03:51:17","VAL2":"72.4780",
"START3":"2014-08-08 03:51:17","END3":"2014-08-31 19:13:17","VAL3":"103.00"},

to this format??????????

var tasks = [
{"startDate":new Date("2014-03-30 00:00:00"),"endDate":new Date("2014-06-17 02:44:11"),"taskName":"AET55V8366","status":49.7950},
{"startDate":new Date("2014-06-17 02:44:11"),"endDate":new Date("2014-07-18 18:13:51"),"taskName":"AET55V8366","status":69.7130},
{"startDate":new Date("2014-07-18 18:13:51"),"endDate":new Date("2014-09-04 05:28:22"),"taskName":"AET55V8366","status":99.00},

{"startDate":new Date("2014-02-19 00:00:00"),"endDate":new Date("2014-05-28 05:23:15"),"taskName":"AET55V8441","status":50.0350},
{"startDate":new Date("2014-05-28 05:23:15"),"endDate":new Date("2014-07-06 12:20:33"),"taskName":"AET55V8441","status":70.0490},
{"startDate":new Date("2014-07-06 12:20:33"),"endDate":new Date("2014-09-03 10:46:30"),"taskName":"AET55V8441","status":100.00},

{"startDate":new Date("2014-06-14 00:00:00"),"endDate":new Date("2014-07-23 09:36:38"),"taskName":"AET55V8445","status":51.7700},
{"startDate":new Date("2014-07-23 09:36:38"),"endDate":new Date("2014-08-08 03:51:17"),"taskName":"AET55V8445","status":72.4780},
{"startDate":new Date("2014-08-08 03:51:17"),"endDate":new Date("2014-08-31 19:13:17"),"taskName":"AET55V8445","status":103.00},
];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var my=[]; 
d3.json("data.json", function(data){ data.forEach(function(d){ my.push(d);}); });
var result=[];
my.forEach(function(d, i){
result.push({"startDate": (d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %X").parse(my[i].START1)),
             "endDate": (d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %X").parse(my[i].END1)),  
             "taskName": my[i].HANDLERID,  
             "status": my[i].VAL1});
result.push({"startDate": (d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %X").parse(my[i].START2)),
             "endDate": (d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %X").parse(my[i].END2)),  
             "taskName": my[i].HANDLERID,  
             "status": my[i].VAL2});
result.push({"startDate": (d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %X").parse(my[i].START3)),
             "endDate": (d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %X").parse(my[i].END3)),  
             "taskName": my[0].HANDLERID,  
             "status": my[i].VAL3});
});
console.log(result);
```

result array is the array, which you are looking for.
Hope it'll help.

data.json is the file containing the format of above data in the question and observe result array.

Comment: Hey! ur awesome! thank you very much for the quick response. This is exactly what i need and it works as i expected!. Thank you very much!

Comment: sure! do i need to click the vote tab like???? im sorry it is my first time here in stackoverflow, how can i do the user-accept???

Comment: You have posted this question, so the user-accept option will be visible only to you, beside of my answer there is a number zero having up arrow and down arrow, there you can find the option.

:)

Comment: ok i already click the check it says i accept the answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to do here.  I can see that you want to extract a start and end date and time, but there are 3 choices, so I just selected 1.  Also, you should know that you can't create new date object inside a json object.  You need to do this outside and pass it into the object.

Anyhow, you should be able to achieve what you're after with the code below (which is similar in concept what saikiran has posted, just a little more compact (and I was too lazy to parse each of the three time objects).

```
d3.json("rawJson.json", function (error, json){
    console.log(json)
    var newJson = [];
    var timeFormat = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

    json.forEach(function (d,i) {
        el = {
            "startDate": timeFormat.parse(d.START1),
            "endDate": timeFormat.parse(d.END1),
            "taskName": d.HANDLERID,
            "status": d.VAL1
        }
        newJson.push(el)
    })
console.log(newJson);
})
```

Just one last thing, the json you posted is quite hard to read.  I would suggest using a linter service like [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/).  It makes your json more human readable and also checks it for structural errors.

Comment: Thank you for the response im sorry if my json data is hard to read. It is my first time to ask a question here and im very glad that i get a quick and helpful response to all of you guyz. Your help is so much appreciated

Comment: hi how can i add a new Date? so my data would look like var tasks = [
{"startDate":new Date("2014-03-30 00:00:00"),"endDate":new Date("2014-06-17 02:44:11"),"taskName":"AET55V8366","status":49.7950}];